# Enabling DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST causes docker & docker-compose commands to fail

Tags: bash, docker, shell, docker-compose

a. Run the below export command in terminal:

```
export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1
```

b. Run :

```
docker-compose up --build -d
```

**FAILURE:**

```
ERRO[0000] Can't close tar writer: io: read/write on closed pipe
error during connect: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.41/build?buildargs=%7B%22EIS_VERSION%22%3A%222.4%22%2C%22GO_VERSION%22%3A%221.12%22%2C%22HOST_TIME_ZONE%22%3A%22Asia%2FKolkata%22%2C%22HTTPS_PROXY%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fproxy-xyz.com%3A911%22%2C%22HTTP_PROXY%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fproxy-xyz.com%3A911%22%2C%22NO_PROXY%22%3A%22127.0.0.1%2Clocalhost%22%2C%22UBUNTU_IMAGE_VERSION%22%3A%2218.04%22%2C%22http_proxy%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fproxy-xyz.com%3A911%22%2C%22https_proxy%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fproxy-xyz.com%3A911%22%2C%22no_proxy%22%3A%22127.0.0.1%2Clocalhost%22%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=dockerfiles%2FDockerfile.eisbase&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&shmsize=0&t=ia_eisbase%3A2.4&target=&ulimits=null&version=1: invalid reference format
Sending build context to Docker daemon  12.55kB
```

I think DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST locks some file wrt docker which causes this error.

Comment: This looks like an error with the build, and specifically an image name in the build. Please include the Dockerfile and compose yaml that would result in this error. See [mcve] for now details.

Comment: Based on the OP, the called URL to build is `http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.41/build` and here are the build args: https://gist.github.com/Sryther/fa7dcd0a2775c8a55221965d69503847

Answer (score 0):

> docker-compose does not have any support for image signing or image signature verification.
>
> — https://github.com/sse-secure-systems/trusted-compose

You need to implement a wrapper for docker-compose or use an existing one in order to work with content trust and docker-compose.

I don't use personnaly trusted-compose but it looks like as a good solution: https://github.com/sse-secure-systems/trusted-compose.

Additional resources:

- [Bringing Content Trust into the World of docker-compose (medium.com)](https://medium.com/sse-blog/bringing-content-trust-into-the-world-of-docker-compose-12836b3537d)
- [Docker Compose not using trusted content during pull (https://github.com/docker/compose)](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4787)

Comment: Specifically for the build command, I don't believe that's true anymore. You can set `COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1` which should be the default now to use docker itself for the build.